# Parameter estimation in log linear models

Tags: estimation, log-linear

Can anyone explain to me how parameter estimation is computed in log linear models? I followed [this paper](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/loglinear.pdf) which is quite good, however I'm a bit confused in the parameter estimation part which is computed by this equation: 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log\,p(y^{(i)}| x^{(i)};v)
$$

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: a short explanation maybe, as we might have millions of features and for each feature we have to estimate the weight. Does this equation estimates all the parameters at once or you have to maximize the function for each parameter??

Comment: That equation is the log-loss.   We want to find $v$ to minimize the loss, which is the same as maximizing the log-loss.  They minimize the loss function by gradient descent.  The calculation of derivatives is a bit silly since these results are all known for the general case of exponential families.

Comment: It would probably be better to find a machine learning textbook and read about "loss functions", and "gradient descent".

Answer (score 1):

This is done with maximum likelihood. The formula you showed is the log likelihood: the logarithm of the probability of observing the data given the parameters $v$. You try to find those parameters that maximize the probability of observing the data you have observed. Pragmatically, you can estimate many log-linear models using just Poisson regression after you have appropriately prepared the data.

Comment: I know that we maximize the equation using maximum likelihood to find v, however my question is: v here is just one parameter or a vector of parameters?

Comment: That depends on what kind of log-linear model you want to estimate. The simplest log-linear model will try to summarize the entire table with just 1 parameter. Needless to say, it often does not fit very well...